# Idle User logout after 5 mins is not working on all the pages of Angular-7 properly?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I am trying to **automatic user logout** after **inactivity** of 5 mins **without any dependencies** or modules using **javascript** but it works fine on first page of my **Angular** but not working on the other routers, on other routers it kept **showing alertbox** even after **click ok**. also if i **switch one page(router)** to another it still counts the countdown of last  page rather then resetting it and counting for new page.

Here is my code -

```
  var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 10; //seconds
    var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
    
    document.onclick = function () {
        _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
    };
    
    document.onmousemove = function () {
        _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
    };
    
    document.onkeypress = function () {
        _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
    };
    
    window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 5000);
    
    function CheckIdleTime() {
        _idleSecondsCounter++;
        var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
        if (oPanel)
            oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter) + "";
        if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
            alert("Time expired! Please Login Again");
            localStorage.clear();
            window.location.replace(location.origin);
        }
    }
```

[image]

it kept showing even **after click** if i write above code on other pages also, What should i try now?

Comment: Integrate this code in Interceptor and set idle definition(for ex: scroll, click etc.) and then if there any session then you have to consider those things as well. Write same code in every page is not good.

Comment: is there any other method apart from interceptor? also i already set idle definition(for ex: scroll, click etc.)

Comment: Try setting `_idleSecondsCounter = 0;` before your alert

Comment: Thanks @yogendarji for the solution but when i switch from one page to another in my angular application it count idle time of last page and hence logout user even after he is active on another page

Comment: @UtsavUpadhyay It will be great if you create a demo code on https://stackblitz.com/ so one can help you.

Comment: @UtsavUpadhyay If I go from page to another, didn't `onclick` method called? otherwise it will work correct

Comment: please use less bold in your question. Italics or underline may be used instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the right place where this particular logic should be placed.

1.) **Logic for the view:** Logics that are applicable only for a particular view should remain in that same component.

2.) **Reused Logic:** Based on your problem statement you should form a service for this particular scenario. Add this logic to that service and reuse it on every single view by injecting this service into each of the view's .ts file.

Go with the second option(Reused Logic), this might work as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much shivam it helps me also if you could elaborate then it will be much better for everyone except me too :)